# Barplots using melt and ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, melt

I have a dataset like this.

```
   > ds
          domanda esito cella
    22870   22870     B    3
    22893   22893     R    4
    16258   16258     P    2
    14684   14684     P    2
    12873   12873     B    1
    12933   12933     B    2
    12047   12047     R    2
    22880   22880     B    3
    11479   11479     P    3
    20836   20836     B    3
```

I need to produce a graph where on the x-axes I have the "cella" elements (from 1 to 49, I've shown you only a part of it). For each cella I want a bar composed by three colours, depending on the P, B, R elements corresponding.
For example, on the cella 2, I want a bar of length 4, colored purple (2 units), blue (1 unit) and red (1 unit).
I know I can use the function `melt` and then `ggplot` (with the ) but I'm not obtaining what I want. Someone could help?

What I have tried:

```
> this.col
 [1] 2 1 3 3 2 2 1 2 3 2
```

Starting from that file of colours (obtained by the column "esito") I have done the following:

```
ds_som.m = melt(ds_som[,2:3],id=c("cella"))

ggplot(data=ds_som.m, aes(x=ds_som.m$cella, y=ds_som.m$value, 
                                     fill=ds_som.m$variable,col=this.col))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+ 
  scale_fill_brewer(direction=-1)+
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Esiti", title.position = "top"))
```

Comment: Do you want a stacked barplot? Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: not obvious that you need to `melt` the data. But make sure cella is a factor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
ds[-1] %>% 
    group_by(cella) %>%
    mutate(n =n()) %>%
    unique() %>% 
    ggplot(., aes(x= cella, y=n, fill=esito)) + 
        geom_bar(stat='identity', position='dodge')
```

Comment: Wondeful code! It works very well (I have just removed "position='dodge' on the geom_bar because I prefer to see the length of the bars).